# How do I get datetime based on files in my directory that starts with a certain name?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, path

My code -

```
for file in os.listdir("C:/Users/hhh/Desktop/autotranscribe/python/Matching"):
    if file.startswith("Master"):
        dfs = pd.read_excel(file, sheet_name=None)
        output = dict()
        for ws, df in dfs.items():
            if ws in ["Added"]:
               continue
            if ws in ["All Members", "Terms"]:
               temp = df

>temp
Company State Address Zip    City
ABC      CA   1 st    86284  LA
```

I want another column that denotes the month the file was created/dropped in the directory minus 1(File Date minus 1 month). So basically, if the file was created on 5/5/22. I want the below

```
Company State Address Zip    City  File Month
ABC      CA   1 st    86284  LA    04-2022
```

My attempt-

```
import datetime
path = "C:/Users/hhh/Desktop/autotranscribe/python/Matching"
# file creation timestamp in float
c_time = os.path.getctime(path)
# convert creation timestamp into DateTime object
dt_c = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(c_time)
temp['File Month'] = (dt_c.replace(day=1) - datetime.timedelta(days=1)).strftime("%m-%Y")
```

But this only works if i set a path and not in my case because my path as you can see above is based on filename that startwith 'Master'. I only want it to be based on the filename and not on os path because os path has multiple files created in it on a daily basis. How do I do this?

Comment: You'll need a full path to determine ctime. Just append (e.g. os.path.join) the string `file` to whatever your source directory is (`C:/Users/hhh/Desk..."`). Besides, I'd suggest to have a look at [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) to simplify some things.

Comment: Thanks for your response @FObersteiner. so you mean there is no solution to my question except for fully defining path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move your code for changing the time into your `for` loop. Also, you don't need `datetime`. `pandas` has all the operations you need.

```
path = "C:/Users/hhh/Desktop/autotranscribe/python/Matching"
for file in os.listdir(path):
    if file.startswith("Master"):
        dfs = pd.read_excel(file, sheet_name=None)
        output = dict()
        for ws, df in dfs.items():
            if ws in ["Added"]:
               continue
            if ws in ["All Members", "Terms"]:
               temp = df
               dt = pd.to_datetime(os.path.getctime(os.path.join(path,file)),unit="s").replace(nanosecond=0)
               temp['File Month'] = (dt.replace(day=1)-pd.DateOffset(days=1)).strftime("%m-%Y")
```

Comment: Hi notpeshal. thank you for your answer. do you mind posting output df please

Comment: I can't. I have no access to your path or files. Why don't you test the answer?

Comment: @not_speshal I have a similar issue as this author. Is it possible for you to help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74114175/how-do-i-retrieve-the-datemodtime-of-each-file-based-on-filename-in-python?noredirect=1#comment130857757_74114175