# How do I retrieve the datemodtime of each file based on filename in python?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

My current process involves looping through my source directory and adding the name of each file to my dataframe in python. I want to get the datemodified for each of these files as well

```
import datetime
import os
import pandas as pd
#set src directory
os.chdir('C:/Users/jj/Desktop/do/Claims/globmove')

def read_files(filenames):
    result = []
    for filename in filenames:
        file = read_sheets(filename)
        file['Filename'] = filename
        result.append(file)
    return pd.concat(result, ignore_index=True)

def modification_date(filename):
    t = os.path.getmtime(filename)
    return datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(t)

folder_path = os.path.abspath('C:/Users/jj/Desktop/do/Claims/globmove')
files = [file for file in os.listdir(folder_path) if file.endswith(".xlsx")]
dfooc = read_files(files)
```

I am able to run this without errors, but the datemodified timestamp currently does not append to the final dataframe- dfooc. How can I get the datemodified to append?

Comment: @FObersteiner sorry about that. made some edits. please let me know if its better now.

Comment: and I forgot to ask, what is `read_sheets` doing, do you import that function from somewhere?

Comment: @FObersteiner readsheets is another part of my process that gets sheetname and row number. Everything works as expected. Its just the datemodified of each file in the directory that i want to append to dfooc. I cannot specify full paths each time as there are new files that will be added in the directory every day so the script just has to loop through

Comment: you do specify the working directory and `folder_path`; if you [glob](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.glob) there for .xlsx files, you'll get full paths, that's what I meant. Anyhow, coming back to the modification timestamp, I don't see `modification_date` being called anywhere in your code?

Comment: @FObersteiner thanks.thats part of my question as well. how do I bring modifcation_date into my code. I tried troubleshooting using file['modifcation_date'] = modifcation_date but there was no new column added. this maybe some rookie mistake im making or something im over engineering. i apologize in advance

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I do it.

```
import os
from pathlib import Path

import pandas as pd
import pendulum


class FileDates:
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.file_type = kwargs.get("file_type")
        self.file_path = kwargs.get("file_path")
        self.path = kwargs.get("path")
        self.tz = pendulum.now().timezone.name

    def main(self) -> pd.DataFrame:
        files = self.get_files()
        dates = self.get_dates(files)

        return pd.DataFrame(list(zip([str(Path(x)).split("/")[-1] for x in files], dates)), columns=["file", "date"])

    def get_files(self) -> list:
        files = [str(x) for x in self.file_path.rglob("*") if x.is_file()]

        return [x for x in files if self.file_type in x]

    def get_dates(self, files: list) -> list:
        return [pendulum.from_timestamp(os.path.getmtime(Path(x))).in_tz(self.tz).to_date_string() for x in files]


file_type = ".xlsx"
file_path = Path(f"{Path.home()}/Desktop/do/Claims/globmove/")
data = FileDates(file_type=file_type, file_path=file_path).main()
```

Comment: Hi Jason, thanks for your answer. unfortunately when i use your code and call data i receive Empty DataFrame
Columns: [file, date]
Index: []

Comment: hmm idk I'm on mac and linux and works for me.

Comment: actually nevermind.Big Thank you! I received the results from your code. I want to mark this answer as correct. However, how do I adapt the results from data into my function of def read_files(filenames):

Comment: All i need from data is the date field to reflect in my final dataframe dfooc

Comment: Hi Jason, if try     file['ModificationDate'] = data('date') i get 

TypeError: 'DataFrame' object is not callable